# Iphone desktop effects

Tags: iphone, drag-and-drop, icons, desktop, shake

How can I make a effect just like iphone desktop?
I want it can show nine icons,when I long press on the icon,it can shake and I can drop and drag the icon...

Does anyone has a demo? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [project](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) that mimic the springboard or the [Three20](http://three20.info/) framework.

Answer (score 2):

I guess following link would help you.

[DragKit](https://github.com/zac/dragkit)